# In string theory, what replaces the black hole singularity?

Tags: black-holes, string-theory, quantum-gravity, singularities

In string theory, what replaces the black hole singularity?

I know that it is possible for a single string to have arbitrarily large energy.  Is a black hole just a single string?

Comment: have a look at this article, the author is a well known theorist https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9607235

Comment: In the Maldacena thesis linked by anna v, there is some possibly relevant material on p. 59 and in figure 6 on p. 60, but I don't understand enough of the paper to know whether this is really relevant.

Comment: I think the answer is something along the lines of "nobody really knows, but there are some interesting proposals"...

Comment: Do you mean by your suggestion that matter collapses into a single string?

Comment: @Wookie I remember reading somewhere that because there are infinitely many string vibrational modes, it is possible for one string to have the entire energy of a black hole.  Is this what actually happens?

Answer (score -2):

Fuzzball theory replaces the singularity at the heart of a black hole.

Please check this page for more information:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzball_(string_theory)

Comment: Fuzzball theory is not standard string theory. Only a small fraction of string theorists accept fuzzball theory.

Comment: @PeterShor What do most believe?

Comment: @Demi .I see that your opinion about my answer has changed.I think that maybe peter shor was right about its acceptance.If that's the reason please say so ,so that I will either delete or edit my answer.